# How to call an imported pallet function from my custom pallet

Tags: pallet

The source code of this vest() function from pallet_vesting https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/pallet_vesting/pallet/enum.Call.html :

```
#[pallet::call]
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
  //pallet_vesting::pallet::Pallet  ... this line is from Rust-Analyzer
        pub fn vest(origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResult {
        let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
        Self::do_vest(who)
    }
```

in my own pallet:

```
use pallet_vesting;
...
    pub fn vest(origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
        let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
        pallet_vesting::Pallet::<T>::vest(origin);
        Ok(().into())
    }
```

I am not sure about the T above... what type should I use?

The error message I got:

```
    the function or associated item `vest` exists for 
struct `pallet_vesting::Pallet<T>`, 
but .. the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
    T: pallet_vesting::Config`
```

Then I replaced the T above, so the function now is...

```
pallet_vesting::Pallet::<T: Config + pallet_vesting::Config>::vest(origin);
```

Then I got two errors:

```
error[E0658]: associated type bounds are unstable
error[E0229]: associated type bindings are not allowed here
```

and I tried the following for the T above... but couldn't get it to work...

```
  where T::pallet_vesting::Config
  T: pallet_vesting::Config
  T: Config
```

Please help!

Comment: Could you expand your code sample a bit? It misses a bit of context needed on the pallet decl besides others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options for [coupling in substrate](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/pallet-coupling/):

LOOSE COUPLING:

Ideally one might want to call:

`T::MyVesting::vest(origin);`

`MyVesting` is an associated type that one would define on your pallet's Config. However `T::MyVesting` must be a trait that has the `vest` fn on it. The eagle eyed will notice that the only trait that the vesting pallet currently implements is the `VestingSchedule` trait which does not, alas, have the `vest` fn on it. So it would need a PR to be submitted to substrate to add such a trait to the Vesting pallet. (not too scary and we'd hand hold you through it)

TIGHT COUPLING:

Shawn says the alternative is to do "tight coupling": make your pallet explicitly depend on the pallet_vesting crate (via Cargo.toml), and then making your pallet's Config depend on the one you wish to call, so your pallet's Config trait would now start like this:

`trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_vesting::Config {`

(ensuring all the trait bounds are satisfied.)

With that done you can call it like this:

`pallet_vesting::pallet::Pallet::<T>::vest(origin)?;`

If you're the end user then tight coupling is not too bad; but if it was part of a library of pallets that people might use in a variety of ways, then one would prefer loose coupling for the added flexibility.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

`T: Config + pallet_vesting::Config` is correct.

Comment: Hi drahnr thank you. I have updated my question. could you have a look?

Comment: Thank you. your answer works

Answer (score 1):

I also cannot give you a full answer, but you can get some inspiration from the [aura_ext](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/b5c8fcbae6903f6cb7611cd97f2d1671f7178126/pallets/aura-ext/src/lib.rs#L141) pallet, which does not have much code, but demonstrates some of the problems you can run into when depending on another pallet.

I think you need to use the `#[pallet::config]` declaration in your pallet probably.