# Is it possible to call dispatched functions on runtime?

Tags: runtime

I want to implement function [transfer_all](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L407) of pallet_balances to my pallet, is it possible to call dispatched functions on runtime?

```
fn my_transfer_all(source: T::AccountId, dest: T::AccountId) -> DispatchResult {
        <T as pallet::Config>::Currency::transfer_all(source, dest, false) // no function or associated item named `transfer_all` found
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `transfer_all` doesn't seem to be on a trait, then you could do it via tight coupling of making your pallet's Config trait have the pallet_balance::Config as a supertrait:

`trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_balance::Config {`

See my answer to this question for more: [How to call an imported pallet function from my custom pallet](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/how-to-call-an-imported-pallet-function-from-my-custom-pallet)

Comment: fwiw, we could also just add `transfer_all` to the `Currency` trait.

Comment: I see acala are using `orml_traits::currency::TransferAll` https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/blob/2d28694ed83c5b2c52082805afb7157217c72a10/traits/src/currency.rs#L364